In SQL Server database mail is not working
Database mail is not working:
Below Error while sending a test mail
Mail not queued. Database Mail is stopped. Use sysmail_start_sp to start Database Mail. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 14641)
Checked all the settings of the service broker and Database Mail XPs all are enabled only. I ran the DBCC CHECKDB command on msdb also no error or inconsistency was found.
while starting the database mail using this query sysmail_start_sp
(dbo.sysmail_help_status_sp;) using this query we checked the status it is in the started state within 20 seconds automatically it returned to the stopped state.
Please help me out and give your suggestions.

Have you checked the error logs to find something related?

I found the below error

Exception Information  ===================  Exception Type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Common.BaseException  Message: The Transaction not longer valid.  Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal  TargetSite: Void ValidateConnectionAndTransaction()  HelpLink: NULL  Source: DatabaseMailEngine  HResult: -2146232832


Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.DataAccess.ConnectionManager.ValidateConnectionAndTransaction()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.DataAccess.ConnectionManager.RollbackTransaction()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.IMailProcess.QueueItemProcesser.GetDataFromQueue(DataAccessAdapter da, Int32 lifetimeMinimumSec)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.IMailProcess.QueueItemProcesser.ProcessQueueItems(String dbName, String dbServerName, Int32 lifetimeMinimumSec, LogLevel loggingLevel, Byte[] encryptionKey, Int32 connectionTimeout)

Here is a solution link link and change the default connection option to SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
